# Apache Service mix development set up

Tags: spring, apache, maven, apache-servicemix

I am trying to set up a maven project for service mix using eclipse indego . Which remote catalog need to add in Maven archetypes. I need to create a bundle/jar for camel route with spring DSL using service mix . Please let me know how to set up this ?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a Create New Maven project ... wizard you just follow.

And then choose the `camel-archetype-spring-dm` to create a Camel route in Spring DSL that can be deployed to OSGi such as Fabric8 / ServiceMix / Karaf